# why parts of my code are missing in jupyter notebook and last checkpoint is not saved

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I took a holiday for two weeks and when I reopened my jupyter notebook when I came back I found there are alot of parts of the code missing. Unfortunately, last checkpoint written above is 3 days before my last 'actual' checkpoint. I don't know what happened. this never happened before and I have been using Jupyter notebook for so many years now.

I tried to restore anything and tried to 'undo deleted cells' and so on but wasn't of any success.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.